# Thermal pad for Hdmi chip and Scei chip

Tags: ps4

Will ps4 pro last longer putting a thermal pad on the Scei chip and Hdmi chip and would it make a difference in cooling?

Comment: A thermal pad is only good if the pad itself is then coming in contact with some sort of material to transfer the heat.  So unless there is some sort of heat spreader the pad can come in contact with, its not going to make a reasonable difference.

Comment: When you say "last longer", are you encountering issues that you believe may be heat related?

Comment: Thank you for your answe

Comment: No, I'm just trying to avoid that. Figure if I'm changing pads and paste wondered if that would help. Ive heard of other people doing that.

Answer (score 2):

#### A thermal pad alone won't do anything.

A thermal pad is simply a pad made out of a material that conducts heat very well. However, that heat still needs somewhere to go. If all you do is put the thermal pad on and do nothing, then you may as well not bother.

What you can do is apply a [heat sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink) on top of the thermal pad. This will allow the air (which is colder than the chip) to touch a much larger surface area, thus heating up more and thus transporting more heat off the chip.

Whether or not this is really necessary is up to you to decide, but if you are set on modifying your PS4, then a thermal pad and a heat sink are certainly an option.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your comment. I won't bother.